# biblatex backref – how to add spaces around the dash?

Tags: spacing, biblatex, back-referencing

I am using `biblatex` with `backref=true`, which generates ranges as e.g. `34–37`. How can I make it e.g. `34 – 37`? The spaces should be non-breakable.

I have tried to redefine `\bibrangedash`, but with no success.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about how you attempted to redefine `\bibrangedash`. Did you try, say, `\def\bibrangedash{\mbox{\,--}\,}`? (The `\mbox` instruction is there to prevent a line break right before the endash.)

Comment: @Mico I tried `\renewcommand*{\bibrangedash}{\,~\textendash~\,}` and other variants, but neither those nor the one you have provided work. Anyway, I had another look at the documentation and I missed an important information, my apologies. The answer is coming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the OP's question is about adding non-breakable spaces, I suggest a solution differing in two respects:

- As an en-dash surrounded by (full) spaces denotes the start/end of an insertion rather than a range, I'd use thin spaces instead.
- Because *"line-breaking in the bibliography is often more difficult than in the body text
  and [...] you can not resort to rephrasing a sentence"* (`biblatex` manual, section 3.8.4), the space following the en-dash should be associated with a high, but finite (for TeX, i.e., <10,000) penalty rather than unbreakable.

The corresponding `biblatex` commands are `\addnbthinspace` and `\addhpthinspace`. See section 4.7.4 of the manual for details.

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{
  \renewcommand*{\bibrangedash}{\addnbthinspace\textendash\addhpthinspace}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I shall accept your answer as it is probably relevant to more languages. I am using normal spaces because of the style requirements I have to meet.

Answer (score 3):

I was inattentive and misinterpreted a bit of the documentation. The following works, should someone need the same:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{
\renewcommand*{\bibrangedash}{~\textendash~}
}
```

Comment: Do you need both the thinspace (`\,`) *and* the regular (unbreakable) interword space (`~`) spacers? I'd think that one or the other spacer would suffice.

Comment: @Mico You are correct, thank you. I used your example and left them there. I need a vacation. :-/